# NodeError [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end, in File createWriteStream

Tags: node.js, fs, cryptojs

On every request, I am trying to decrypt an encrypted image, and provide a response based on that. I started my server, on first request, its decrypting the file, and sending a proper response, while on next request, it trying to decrypt, but not storing any data into new file, and at the end throwing an error "ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END", and my server crushed down.

My decrypt function is

```
let decrypt = Crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-ctr', 'random_string');
async function decryptFile(encryptedFileDetails) {
    try {
        // write you code here..
        let decryptPromise = new Promise(async (decryptResolve) => {
            let r = FS.createReadStream(source);
            let w = FS.createWriteStream(destination);
            // start pipe
            r.pipe(decrypt).pipe(w);
            w.on('finish', function () {
                console.log('Decrypted file written to disk!');
                decryptResolve();
            });
        });
        await decryptPromise;
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}


The error message I am receiving is

NodeError [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:248:12)
    at Decipher.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:296:5)
    at ReadStream.ondata (_stream_readable.js:708:20)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:287:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:268:11)
    at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
    at lazyFs.read (internal/fs/streams.js:181:12)
    at FSReqWrap.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:467:17) Emitted 'error' event at:
    at errorOrDestroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:107:12)
    at Decipher.onerror (_stream_readable.js:732:7)
    at Decipher.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at errorOrDestroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:107:12)
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:250:3)
    at Decipher.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:296:5)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at FSReqWrap.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:467:17)
</pre>
```

Comment: What is the `decrypt` function?  Is it from some module?  Can we look at the doc for how it's supposed to be used?

Comment: `let decrypt = Crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-ctr', 'random_string');` a crypto decipher function

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution.

I was trying to use the same cipher stream object multiple times by declaring it globally. but one cipher stream can be used once and nexxt time we have to create another object.

```
async function decryptFile(encryptedFileDetails) {
    try {
        // write you code here..
        let decryptPromise = new Promise(async (decryptResolve) => {
            let decrypt = Crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-ctr', 'random_string');
            let r = FS.createReadStream(source);
            let w = FS.createWriteStream(destination);
            // start pipe
            r.pipe(decrypt).pipe(w);
            w.on('finish', function () {
                console.log('Decrypted file written to disk!');
                decryptResolve();
            });
        });
        await decryptPromise;
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}
```